# Authenticate SignalR call through ADAL JS

Tags: angularjs, signalr, adal

I have a web api hosted on Azure having Azure AD authentication configured and running properly (all controllers have the Authorized attribute).
The front-end runs AngularJS and authentication of the http requests is implemented by using the amazing ADAL JS library (adalAuthenticationServiceProvider).

Beside the web api I also have a SignalR hub that I'd like to 'protect'. More specifically I need to call (invoke) a method of the Hub from the AngularJS client code. Basically I need to have the Context.User populated in the Hub method.

Any idea how to also authenticate a SignalR invoke under these circumstances?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can supply token on query parameter as suggested in https://auth0.com/blog/2014/01/15/auth-with-socket-io/ and then process token on your backend